# Using BeautifulSoup to parse data within the tags/results

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

So I have the below code to parse the link and title, which works fine but I'd like to parse just one season. As you can see from the link/sample below, the season data is contained within the tags so searching for the tag itself obviously won't work. How do I I filter out each season at a time? Any help would be appreciated.

```
def get_playable_podcast0(soup0):
    subjects = []
    for content in soup0.find_all('item'):
        try:
            link = content.find('enclosure')
            link = link.get('url')
            print("\n\nLink: ", link)
            title = content.find('title')
            title = title.get_text()
        except AttributeError:
            continue
        item = {
                'url': link,
                'title': title,
                'thumbnail': "(imagelink)",
        }
        subjects.append(item)
    return subjects
def compile_playable_podcast0(playable_podcast0):
    items = []
    for podcast in playable_podcast0:
        items.append({
            'label': podcast['title'],
            'thumbnail': podcast['thumbnail'],
            'path': podcast['url'],
            'is_playable': True,
    })
    return items
```

Sample from link to be parsed:[.XML link](https://www.cbc.ca/podcasting/includes/uncover.xml)

```
<item>
    <title>S7 E5</title>
    <enclosure url="https://cbc.mc.tritondigital.com/CBC_UNCOVER_P/media/uncover-Wm2KHbCU-20200707.mp3?ttag=season:7" length="41747493" type="audio/mpeg"/>
    <itunes:season>7</itunes:season>
    <itunes:episode>5</itunes:episode>
    <itunes:episodeType>full</itunes:episodeType>
</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select `season` and cast it to an `int`. But beware, some items don't have season: I put default season of `1` if the season is missing:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url='https://www.cbc.ca/podcasting/includes/uncover.xml'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'xml')

for item in soup.select('item'):
    season = item.select_one('season')
    if season:
        season = int(season.text)
    else:
        season = 1  # default season is 1

    if season == 7:
        title = item.select_one('subtitle').text
        link = item.select_one('enclosure')['url']
        print(title)
        print(link)
        print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Glen faces new horrors while being locked up in prison. But then he makes a connection with someone on the outside who provides a lifeline — and possibly, a route to freedom.
https://cbc.mc.tritondigital.com/CBC_UNCOVER_P/media/uncover-Wm2KHbCU-20200707.mp3?ttag=season:7
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The day after Glen is convicted of murder he starts to work on his appeal. A new lawyer and an ex-RCMP private investigator find fresh evidence that should help get Glen a new trial.
https://cbc.mc.tritondigital.com/CBC_UNCOVER_P/media/uncover-SEmcfxRf-20200630.mp3?ttag=season:7
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The trial of Glen Assoun for the second degree murder of Brenda Way starts on June 1, 1999. But within days, the trial takes an expected turn, and events begin to unfold that place Glen in an impossible situation.
https://cbc.mc.tritondigital.com/CBC_UNCOVER_P/media/uncover-ba86fI2w-20200623.mp3?ttag=season:7
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The police investigation into Brenda Way’s murder is going nowhere until a new investigator is assigned to the case. Suddenly, new witnesses and evidence start to appear,  and all of it points in one direction.
https://cbc.mc.tritondigital.com/CBC_UNCOVER_P/media/uncover-EFf9iIoa-20200616.mp3?ttag=season:7
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
On November 12, 1995, 28-year-old Brenda Way is found murdered behind an apartment building in Dartmouth, Nova Scotia.  Investigative journalist Tim Bousquet  discovers, right in his own neighbourhood,  a community of sex workers and a pattern of violence that indicates this is not the first time.
https://cbc.mc.tritondigital.com/CBC_UNCOVER_P/media/uncover-KuI2HiIz-20200616.mp3?ttag=season:7
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Twenty-five years ago, Brenda Way was found murdered in Dartmouth, Nova Scotia. A botched investigation followed, resulting in the wrongful imprisonment of Glen Assoun—who served more than 17 years for the crime. How could one investigation go so wrong? And where is the justice for Brenda?
https://cbc.mc.tritondigital.com/CBC_UNCOVER_P/media/uncover-EfLwkf1p-20200611.mp3?ttag=season:7
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if I'm understanding your question correctly:

```
def get_playable_podcast0(soup0):
    subjects = []
    for content in soup0.find_all('item'):
          desiredSeason = "7"
          if content.find('itunes:season').text != desiredSeason:
             continue
          # rest of code as before
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative solution that's based on extracting the season from the episode url using regex, since the URL's seem to always end with '?ttag=season:<season_number>'. From what I can tell, this seems to be the most reliable source of information when it comes to season numbering.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

resp = requests.get('https://www.cbc.ca/podcasting/includes/uncover.xml')
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text)
epi_ls = get_playable_podcast0(soup) # using your function here
seasons = {}
for ep in epi_ls:
    ep_url = ep.get('url')
    regex_match = re.search("(?<=season:)[0-9]+", ep_url)
    if not regex_match:
        continue
    season_number = regex_match[0]
    if season_number in seasons:
        seasons[season_number].append(ep)
    else:
        seasons[season_number] = [ep]
```

There are a few episodes that don't seem to belong to a particular season, e. g. a season 1/3/5 special (I saw something like that), so this doesn't work for them I think. A benefit of this method is that it's not affected by how the podcast authors seem to have registered the wrong itunes:season/itunes:episode for a few episodes. An example of this is 'S3 E3: Meet Me Under The Clock', which is registered with `<itunes:season>1</itunes:season>` and `<itunes:episode>8</itunes:episode>`.